# Dificuldade para concluir animação de slide

Tags: html, css

Fala amigos,

estou tentando fazer um slide usando animations com a propriedade opacity.
Quero que a primeira foto seja o ponto de partida e não sofra com o efeito da `animation`, então setei none para a mesma.
Ademais, coloquei um `animation-delay` para que cada foto receba o efeito na hora certa.
Porém obviamente isso extende a duração do efeito, que deveria ter no total 25 segundos apenas (5 segundos por foto).
Estou com dificuldade de entender a lógica dos keyframes, é a primeira vez que tento reproduzir algo do tipo.
Segue o código CSS:

```
@keyframes carrossel {

    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    20% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
    }
    40% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
    }
    60% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
    }
    80% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
    }
}

.banner:nth-child(1) {
    animation: none;
}

.banner:nth-child(2) {
    animation-delay: 5s;
    opacity: 0;
}

.banner:nth-child(3) {
    animation-delay: 10s;
    opacity: 0;
}

.banner:nth-child(4) {
    animation-delay: 15s;
    opacity: 0;
}

.banner:nth-child(5) {
    animation-delay: 20s;
    opacity: 0;
}

.banner {   /* Div que contém as imagens */ 
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    animation-name: carrossel;
    animation-duration: 25s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
```

**TRECHO DO CÓDIGO HTML:**

```
<header>
    <nav class="menu">
        <div id="barra-superior">
            <img src="_logos/montanha (1).png" id="img_logo">
            <span id="logo">Get.Started.Now!</span>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="cabecalho">
        <img src="_fotos/banner.jpg" class="banner">
        <img src="_fotos/foto-montanha.jpg" class="banner">
        <img src="_fotos/mar.jpg" class="banner">
        <img src="_fotos/trilhos.jpg" id="banner" class="banner">
        <img src="_fotos/fogueira.jpg" id="banner" class="banner">
        <img src="_icons/inferior.png" class="seta" id="seta_movimenta">
        <span id="frase"><br><br></span>
    </div>
</header>
```

Quando simplifico para from to (que pensei ser o correto) todas as imagens sofrem o efeito meio que simultaneamente, não entendi porquê. Para piorar, a última imagem entra em loop com a penúltima, também não entendi este comportamento.
Como fazer as imagens irem passando organicamente, voltando para a primeira imagem no final e continuando infinitamente? Onde estou errando?
Thxx guys!

Comment: Cara seria legal vc incluir o HTML na pergunta, ajudaria bastante a te responder e simular o problema

Comment: FALA @hugocsl segue o trecho do código em html. Ajuda? Obrigado irmão!